# Will the design of semiconductors such as CPU change in the future?

Tags: design, cpu, semiconductors

Only the look of it, a quadrilateral with pins around it. Not the material or what's inside.

Will there be a major change in the appearance of a CPU in 20 or 50 years?

This is question is coming from the lifespan of a logo which has a CPU illustration and I guessed graphicdesign.stackexchange.com is not the right place to ask it.

Comment: Over 20 years ago, CPU's stopped being quadrilateral with pins around them. They are typically some type of grid array.

Comment: have you actually went to website that sells modern CPUs? Could you buy a single CPU that looked like that? I haven't seen a logo like you describe it used for a CPU in a long time (or at least, in modern software)

Comment: @MarcusMüller I think you misunderstood my purpose. My question is not technical. See https://goo.gl/8aJqEm in illustration they're around. It's sad that you voted down based on the first sentence and didn't even read the last paragraph.

Comment: *My question is not technical.* Then why ask it here and complain that someone does not understand your questions. This is a technical/engineering site so you're expected to ask such questions and can expect technical answers.

Comment: Semiconductors rely on photolithography, and probably always will. That process requires a plane. Semiconductor wafers are cut into chips in a grid. So yes, semi's are flat rectangles. Input/Output might become optical - hard to say how that would affect packaging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will there be a major change in the appearance of a CPU in 20 or 50 years?

Almost certainly.

> This is question is coming from the lifespan of a logo which has a CPU illustration.

It may not be a problem. We still use the floppy disk symbol for *File save* but there's a whole generation who have never seen one.

Comment: That's exactly my concern. Floppy died so quickly that no one born after 2000 will notice the floppy inside Dell logo but CPU shape still remains.

Comment: I have an old oscilloscope with a floppy drive. So I bought a USB floppy drive so I could get images off of it. They are dead for practical purposes, but you can still by floppies and drives. None of this changes your main point, however.